# Unable to build nextjs locally

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

When I commit the code to github then vercel will build just fine but locally I cannot build it. I want to test a getStaticPaths but can't.

The error I am getting locally is `ReferenceError: group is not defined` but there is no variable usage that is not defined and vercel gets the same code without it giving this error.

I rebooted (OSX maybe cached some old files) but that didn't work either.

The command in package.json scripts is `"build": "next build",` and I run it with `yarn run build`.

Running `next -p 8080` will run the project in dev mode without any errors but that doesn't run getStaticPaths at all.

Comment: Better to post your Error trace as well along with your problem.

Comment: @VenkatLokeswar What is an error trace and how do I get one?